# magit ediff conflicts wordwise

Tags: magit, ediff

During a `magit-rebase` I'm running into conflicts on single long lines, where I'd like to take some parts of the line from the A and some from the B buffer.

After hitting `* -refine current region` within `magit-ediff-dwim` I can view the wordwise diff between two buffers. However, the actual diff chunks to choose from are much bigger. Is it possible to update these chunks so I can resolve the conflicts word by word (similar to `ediff-regions-wordwise`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good question.  This feels like it should be standard.  With a little digging into the code and experimenting,
this *seems* at first glance to work:

From the ediff control window:

- <kbd>M-:</kbd> `(setq ediff-word-mode t)` <kbd>RET</kbd>
- <kbd>!</kbd> to run `ediff-update-diffs`

Which we can encapsulate in a command (which I've bound to <kbd>.</kbd> in the ediff control buffer) like so:

```el
(defun my-ediff-toggle-word-mode ()
  "Toggle between linewise and wordwise comparisons."
  (interactive)
  (setq ediff-word-mode (not ediff-word-mode))
  (ediff-update-diffs))

(add-hook 'ediff-startup-hook #'my-ediff-startup-hook)

(defun my-ediff-startup-hook ()
  "Custom `ediff-startup-hook' behaviours."
  (define-key ediff-mode-map (kbd ".") #'my-ediff-toggle-word-mode))
```

Note that `ediff-word-mode` disables refinements, so you would need to use <kbd>@</kbd> to restore that (if desired) after toggling back to linewise diffs.

If you don't experience any issues with this (let me know), then I think this should be a feature-request (<kbd>M-x</kbd> `report-emacs-bug`).

Comment: This works exactly as expected, thank you very much! I agree that it would be useful to have this included in ediff (including a description of the keybinding in the ediff control panel).

Comment: I suspect it should either be an additional state for `@` to cycle through, or else that `C-u @` should be used, as it feels like a part of the refinement functionality.